# How to convert '\\x41' to '\x41' in c?

Tags: c

Probably the question has already been answered, but unfortunately many many attempts didn't work for me :(

Precisely said, let's assume I have:

```
char buf[] = "\\x41\\x41\\x41\\x41"
```

Basically I want to convert it into

```
char con[] = "\x41\x41\x41\x41"
```

I tried by splitting the buf into arrays like:

```
buf1[]="41",buf2[]="41", buf3[]="41", buf4[]="41"
char newbuf[30];
sprintf(newbuf, "%2x%2x%2x%2x", buf1,buf2,buf3,buf4);
printf("%s:%llx:%p:%d",newbuf,newbuf,newbuf, strlen(newbuf))
```

and the output I get is: `ffffe3f0ffffe410ffffe430ffffe450ffffe470ffffe490:7fffffffe3b0:0x7fffffffe3b0:48`

But the output I wish to see is `AAAA`

So is there something I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you actually want do.
If you print the C string "\\x41\\x41\\x41\\x41" it shows \x41\x41\41\x41 because the double back-slash means a single back-slash, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences.
If you print the C string "\x41\x41\x41\x41" it shows AAAA because \x followed by two hexadecimal digits shows the relating ASCII charachter.

Comment: it would show as `AAAA` but if you had `\x41` but when you have `\\x41` the first backslash is escaped

Comment: Your explanation is not clear, but I think you want to replace all \x41 in the string by the corresponding char. In that case, you can try split the string with strtok() with the '\' as delimiters, prepend a 0 on the chunks and use strtol() on the remaining 0x41 to convert them to chars. Then you sprintf() %c all the chars together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void parseCstring(const char buf[], char con[])
{
    int i=0, j=0;
    unsigned char x;
    while ( (x = buf[i]) != '\0')
    {
        if ( (x=='\\') && (buf[i+1]=='x') && (isxdigit(buf[i+2])) && (isxdigit(buf[i+3])) )
        {
            unsigned int val;
            sscanf(&(buf[i+2]),"%2x", &val);
            x=(unsigned char)val;
            i+=3;
        }
        con[j++]=x;
        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char buf[] = "\\x41\\x42\\x42\\x41 was great\\x21";
    char con[40];
    printf("%s\n",buf);
    parseCstring(buf, con);
    printf("%s\n",con);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your answer worked as well, but unfortunately I can accept only one answer, but thank you anyway